# Insert and Obtain Objects Array into/from ListBox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I've got a Product class, with a Description, Stock, and Price, and I need to insert the Description in a Listbox, which I did with:

```
Me.ListBox1.DataSource = productArray
Me.ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Descrition"
Me.ListBox1.ValueMember = "_Description"
```

but now, I need to obtain the price and stock of the selected item to operate with them, but I can't find a way to do so.

Comment: Cast the `ListBox1.SelectedItem` to your Product class.  That doesn't look like a particularly effective ValueMember, by the way.

Comment: `Dim selectedProduct As Product = DirectCast(Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem, Product)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `SelectedItem` back to the Product type.

```
Private Sub lsb_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
 Dim product As Product = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, Product)
 Debug.WriteLine(product.Stock.ToString)
 Debug.WriteLine(product.Price.ToString)
End Sub
```